# Windows Vista not accepting product key on new partition

Tags: windows-vista, product-key

I have installed Windows Vista on a new partition, but it will not accept the product key. I don't want to have to buy another product key. Can anyone help?

Comment: How many copies of Vista on the same or different PCs are you using with the same key? How many times (roughly) do you remember using the same key to activate Vista?

Comment: The same copy of vista is installed on two segments on the same PC, including the one where it will not accept the product key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing activation issues use the [phone-based activation method](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/84488-activate-vista-phone.html). If the automated service doesn't help you can talk to a Microsoft rep who can aid you further.

[image: 1]